# Unsuccessfully resized NTFS partition using Gparted, now it has enlarged partition size but filesystem is not resized/grown

Tags: linux, ntfs, gparted

I tried to unmount the NTFS partition, it failed, so I

```
umount -l /dev/sda5
```

and then tried resizing partition of ~200GB to 309.99GB. It resized in an instant, I was instructed to restart system by Gparted. It seems now the partition size was resized to 309.99GB, but the filesystem shows ~200GB with 108GB unallocated.

I still can mount and access all files. [These are my partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkJUf.png)

I Check Partition on gparted, this is the error I get,

```
GParted 0.25.0 --enable-libparted-dmraid --enable-online-resize

Libparted 3.2

Check and repair file system (ntfs) on /dev/sda5  00:00:01    ( ERROR )

calibrate /dev/sda5  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )

path: /dev/sda5 (partition)
start: 1128448
end: 651218943
size: 650090496 (309.99 GiB)
check file system on /dev/sda5 for errors and (if possible) fix them  00:00:01    ( ERROR )

ntfsresize -i -f -v /dev/sda5  00:00:01    ( ERROR )

ntfsresize v2015.3.14AR.1 (libntfs-3g)
Device name : /dev/sda5
NTFS volume version: 3.1
Cluster size : 4096 bytes
Current volume size: 214748361216 bytes (214749 MB)
Current device size: 332846333952 bytes (332847 MB)
Checking for bad sectors ...
Checking filesystem consistency ...
Inode is corrupt (523): Input/output error
Inode is corrupt (1179): Input/output error
Inode is corrupt (1624): Input/output error
Inode is corrupt (1986): Input/output error
Inode is corrupt (2441): Input/output error
Inode is corrupt (2454): Input/output error
Inode is corrupt (3067): Input/output error
Inode is corrupt (3178): Input/output error
Inode is corrupt (3667): Input/output error
Inode is corrupt (3776): Input/output error
Inode is corrupt (6049): Input/output error
Inode is corrupt (6751): Input/output error
Inode is corrupt (7178): Input/output error
Inode is corrupt (7513): Input/output error
Inode is corrupt (8199): Input/output error
Inode is corrupt (8240): Input/output error
Inode is corrupt (8249): Input/output error
Inode is corrupt (8259): Input/output error
Inode is corrupt (8748): Input/output error
Inode is corrupt (8996): Input/output error
Inode is corrupt (10241): Input/output error
Inode is corrupt (11164): Input/output error
Inode is corrupt (11392): Input/output error
100.00 percent completed
Accounting clusters ...
Cluster accounting failed at 9213941 (0x8c97f5): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 12913555 (0xc50b93): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 12913556 (0xc50b94): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 12997529 (0xc65399): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 14930776 (0xe3d358): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 18002283 (0x112b16b): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 18006376 (0x112c168): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 18057343 (0x113887f): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 18057344 (0x1138880): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 20102360 (0x132bcd8): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 20336434 (0x1364f32): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 20342801 (0x1366811): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 20363408 (0x136b890): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 22761869 (0x15b518d): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 23186158 (0x161caee): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 23190248 (0x161dae8): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 23229588 (0x1627494): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 23286726 (0x16353c6): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 25225024 (0x180e740): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 25229120 (0x180f740): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 25331016 (0x1828548): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 25331017 (0x1828549): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 26032472 (0x18d3958): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 26032473 (0x18d3959): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 26032474 (0x18d395a): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 26032475 (0x18d395b): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 26032476 (0x18d395c): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 26872264 (0x19a09c8): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 31681239 (0x1e36ad7): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 31869833 (0x1e64b89): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 31869834 (0x1e64b8a): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 31890301 (0x1e69b7d): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 33387641 (0x1fd7479): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 33387642 (0x1fd747a): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 33387643 (0x1fd747b): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 33387644 (0x1fd747c): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 34055504 (0x207a550): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 34059600 (0x207b550): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 34171512 (0x2096a78): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 35942016 (0x2246e80): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 35946112 (0x2247e80): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 36806769 (0x231a071): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 37213527 (0x237d557): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 37217624 (0x237e558): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 37245163 (0x23850eb): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 38389268 (0x249c614): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 39450765 (0x259f88d): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 39454856 (0x25a0888): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 39497605 (0x25aaf85): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 39497606 (0x25aaf86): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 41476236 (0x278e08c): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 41480688 (0x278f1f0): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 41622533 (0x27b1c05): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 41626624 (0x27b2c00): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 41653232 (0x27b93f0): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 42148141 (0x283212d): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 43912656 (0x29e0dd0): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 47597952 (0x2d64980): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 47602048 (0x2d65980): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 47610240 (0x2d67980): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 47774080 (0x2d8f980): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 47778176 (0x2d90980): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 47786368 (0x2d92980): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 47839879 (0x2d9fa87): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 47843976 (0x2da0a88): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 47852168 (0x2da2a88): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 47884936 (0x2daaa88): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 47889032 (0x2daba88): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 47897224 (0x2dada88): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 48389360 (0x2e25cf0): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 48389361 (0x2e25cf1): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 48389362 (0x2e25cf2): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 48389363 (0x2e25cf3): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 48389364 (0x2e25cf4): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 48389365 (0x2e25cf5): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 48389366 (0x2e25cf6): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 48389367 (0x2e25cf7): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 48389368 (0x2e25cf8): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 48389369 (0x2e25cf9): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 48389370 (0x2e25cfa): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 48415965 (0x2e2c4dd): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 49827041 (0x2f84ce1): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 49827042 (0x2f84ce2): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 49827043 (0x2f84ce3): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 49827044 (0x2f84ce4): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 49827045 (0x2f84ce5): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 49827046 (0x2f84ce6): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 49827047 (0x2f84ce7): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 50553627 (0x303631b): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 50764942 (0x3069c8e): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 50811033 (0x3075099): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 50832504 (0x307a478): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 50836600 (0x307b478): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Filesystem check failed! Totally 93 cluster accounting mismatches.
ERROR: NTFS is inconsistent. Run chkdsk /f on Windows then reboot it TWICE!
The usage of the /f parameter is very IMPORTANT! No modification was
and will be made to NTFS by this software until it gets repaired.
========================================
```

If I backup all files on that disk and delete to create new partition, will it go corrupt?

PS. I don't have access to Windows

Comment: I think to do ntfs resize. Follow this link http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179577/how-do-i-resize-a-windows-partition-without-using-gparted

Comment: First of all, backup the whole partition by making an image of it. After that, try to restore the original partition layout using TestDisk ran from a live DVD/USB.

Comment: I didn't backup the partition, but I did recover partition table through testdisk, then went on to download a MS DaRT iso to run chkdsk. Worked brilliantly.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so solution was to,
run `testdisk` => Analyse => Select all required & correct Partitions and set as Primary/Logical => Rewrite partition table

Once done, it's best to get a Windows based boot CD or have Windows (Installed or Boot). Boot into either.

Then, run `diskpart` on command prompt => `list volume` to show drive letters.
Exit `diskpart` or in a new cmd prompt, run `chkdsk E: /R` [Replace E: with drive letter].

You'll probably get all files back like me.

If any of your files are missing after that, use `testdisk` to recover them. There are plenty of guides online on this.

PS. If you think you have all files before starting this process, do a backup image as suggested by Andrea Lazzarotto